# How to access the filename from a blob while copying into Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to copy a bunch of files from a folder in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 2 using Data Factory.  I need to access the filenames of the blobs that I am copying at runtime so that I can inspect it and parse the name to retrieve important metadata.  Unfortunately, I do not see a way to do this using Data Factory V2 on Azure.  If anyone knows how to do this it would be greatly appreciated if you shared this with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get an idea of [Get Metadata Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity) in Azure Data Factory which can be used to retrieve metadata of any data in Azure Data Factory.

However,only below connectors are supported so far:

[image]

Since your data is stored in ADL Gen2,you could try to transfer the data from ADL Gen2 to Azure Blob Storage.Then use Metadata Activity to access the file name in folder:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity#get-a-folders-metadata

Comment: This is really great.  Should provide all the info I need if I'm getting files from azure blob storage or other supported sources.  Hopefully they will support ADLA Gen 2 very soon.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps to copy the filenames from 'Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2' at runtime.

**Step 1)** File name and the file type can be retrieved using the **'Get Metadata' activity**. Mention the File list as 'Child items' to retrieve the metadata information of the folders and the files.

[image: Get Metadata - settings]

Output of 'Get Metadata' activity below

[image: Output of Get Metadata activity]

'Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2' connector is also supported in 'Get Metadata' activity.

[image: Microsoft Page Page]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity

**Step 2)** Iterate through the files using **'For Each' activity**. 'For Each' activity Settings/ Items use the expression `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems` to retrieve the input from the 'Get Metadata' activity.

**Step 3)** Use **'Copy data' activity** to copy the required files. Specify the respective source and the Sink setting from which source to target you would like to move the files.

Below is the complete pipeline.

[image: complete pipeline]